# Combine two functions that must work one after another (with trigger)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two working functions. One of them is myFunction with a trigger. Is protects the row of the cell when any information is entered in this cell in Column4.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  const sheetNames = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']; // Please set the sheet names you want to run the script.

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const value = range.getValue();
  const row = range.getRow();
  if (!sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName()) || range.getColumn() != 4 || row == 2 || value == "") return;
  const p = sheet.getRange(`B${row}:D${row}`).protect();
  const owner = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  p.getEditors().forEach(f => {
    const email = f.getEmail();
    if (email != owner) p.removeEditor(email);
  });
}
```

Another function is an onEdit function. It adds date in Column1 when I enter information in Column4. The date appears in the same row with the cell in Column4.

```
function onEdit() {
var colToCheck = 4;

    // Offset from the input [row, column]
    var dateOffset = [0, -3];

    // Sheets to proceed on
    var sheetNames = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    var name = sheet.getName();

    if (sheetNames.indexOf(name) > -1) {

      var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
      var col = cell.getColumn();

      if (col == colToCheck) {

          var dateTimeCell = cell.offset(dateOffset[0], dateOffset[1]);
          dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

How these two functions can be combined in one sheet?

Comment: I think  you might need an installable onEdit function for myFunction(e) because your removing editors.  But admittedly I've never done this before.

Comment: if you learn how to use all of the data in the event object you could save a lot of time; `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()` is the same as `e.range.getSheet();` `cell.getColumn()` is that same as `e.range.columnStart` which is no function call at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added two separate functions to one sheet: the one with trigger and the one onEdit as two different codes. And they work as I need. So, we do not need to combine them somehow. They just work one after another. First, the one onEdit function works, and as it adds info to the necessary cell, the function with trigger starts working.

Comment: This is not completely clear. If they are working, why not call MyFunction() from OnEdit()? To make sure they go in order you can add SpreadsheetApp.flush() between the two. Perhaps I misunderstood.